# How to add cv_bridge and image_transport package to compile in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: catkin-make, tutorial, ubuntu, cv-bridge, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed ROS indigo in Raspberry Pi by following [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi). I also installed opencv using [this](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40). I can view the continuous image using ROS. Now I want to convert CV  image from Raspberry Pi to ROS image and send it thru the node and read it from ubuntu PC. I'm following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials). I am having the following error after catkin_make. I think I missing dependencies or package. Please help.

> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'learning_image_transport'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(learning_image_transport)
> CMake Error at
> /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake:106
> (message):   Project 'cv_bridge'
> specifies
> '/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include'
> as an include dir,   which is not
> found.  It does neither exist as an
> absolute directory nor in
> '/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge//home/pi/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include'.
> Ask the maintainer 'Vincent Rabaud
> vincent.rabaud@gmail.com' to fix it.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75
> (find_package)
> learning_image_transport/CMakeLists.txt:7
> (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205853/how-to-add-cv_bridge-and-image_transport-package-to-compile-in-raspberry-pi?/) by [aknay](https://answers.ros.org/users/21898/aknay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-03-25**:
Did you install cv_bridge in your workspace? I believe it depends on openCV, so you will need that, too.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-03-25**:
Alternatively, you could have an issue with your local copy of `cv_bridge`... did you somehow delete the `include/` directory inside of `/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/`

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-29**:
hi joq , could you please tell me how install cv_bridge itself?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-31**:
Add the https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv.git repository to your workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you @joq and @jarvisschultz

I am able to run the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials) now. I am not sure which steps solved the problem.
Basically I followed the link mentioned in the posted problem in [Resolving Dependencies with rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws $ rosinstall_generator common_msgs sensor_msgs image_transport --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws $ wstool merge -t src indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws $ wstool up -t src
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws $ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y -r --os=debian:wheezy
```

There was long compilation and I encountered the following problem at the end. Just for the record.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"dynamic_reconfigure" with any of the following names:

dynamic_reconfigureConfig.cmake
dynamic_reconfigure-config.cmake
```

I decided to do final try with new catkin work-space. Luckily, I can run the tutorial on new work-space and I can see published and subscribed topics. Next step, I will try to see physical image with rqt.

---

Originally posted by [aknay](https://answers.ros.org/users/21898/aknay/) with karma: 36 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Salahuddin_Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32372/salahuddin_khan/) on 2018-07-12**:
Hey luck on solving this error? I am trying to compile gmapping on Raspberry Pi and after installing a few dependencies I'm now stuck at this error.